# How to get my program to read thru errors

Tags: c++

I have an assignment for school in which the goal is to read data from a text file, and output calculations made with the info. I've gotten the inputing and outputting mostly down, but our prof wants us to include error checking aswell. I've done error checking for strings, and now im working on ints/doubles. The only issue is when i try to use the sample error input file he provided, my while loop dosen't fire at all.

```
bool isWord(string s)
{
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i)
    {
        if (::isdigit(s[i])){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}


int main()
{
ifstream inData;
ofstream outData;
inData.open("inData.txt");
outData.open("outData.txt");
//check for Error
if (inData.fail()){
    cout << "Error opening file!" << endl;
    exit(1);
}
if (outData.fail()){
    cout << "Error opening file!" << endl;
    exit(1);
}

double rWidth;
double rLength;
double cRad;
double number = 0;
string fName;
string lName;
string word;
int age;
int i = 0;
int savings;
int count = 0;
int people = 0;
int tAge = 0;
int tSavings = 0;
string names[256];
double tLength = 0;
double tWidth = 0;
double tArea = 0;
double perimeter = 0;
double tRad = 0;
double tCarea = 0;
double tCirc = 0;

while(inData >> rWidth >> rLength >> cRad >> fName >> lName >> age >> savings){
    cout << rWidth << " " << rLength << " "  << cRad << " "  << fName << " "  << lName << " "  << age << " "  << savings << "\n";
    stringstream fNameStream(fName);
    stringstream lNameStream(lName);
    while (fNameStream >> word)
    {
        if (isWord(fName))
        {
            names[count++] = word;
        }
        else
        {
            names[count++] = "John";
        }
    }
    while (lNameStream >> word)
    {
        if (isWord(lName))
        {
            names[count++] = word;
        }
        else
        {
            names[count++] = "Doe";
        }
    }

    istringstream widthStream(rWidth);

    while (widthStream >> number)
    {
        if (widthStream >> number)
        {
            widthStream >> rWidth;
        }
        else
        {
            rWidth = 0.0;
        }
    }


    tLength = tLength + rLength;
    tWidth = tWidth + rWidth;
    perimeter = perimeter + (2*(rWidth+rLength));
    tArea = tArea + (rWidth*rLength);
    tRad = tRad + cRad;
    tCarea = tCarea + pow(cRad, 2) * M_PI;
    tCirc = tCirc + (2*M_PI*cRad);
    tAge = tAge + age;
    tSavings = tSavings + savings;
}
cout << tLength << "\n";
cout << tWidth << "\n";
cout << perimeter << "\n";
cout << tArea << "\n";
cout << tCarea << "\n";
cout << tCirc << "\n";
cout << tAge << "\n";
cout << tSavings < "\n";
cout << count << "\n";
while (i < count)
{
    cout << names[i] << " ";
    i++;
}
outData << "Rectangle: \n";
outData << "The total length= " << tLength << ", width= " << tWidth << ", area= " << tArea << "\n";
outData << "Perimeter= " << perimeter << "\n\n";
outData << "Circle:\n";
outData << "The total radius= " << tRad << ", area= " << tCarea << ", circumference= " << tCirc << "\n\n";
outData << "People:\n" << "Total number of people= " << count << "\n" << "Total Age= " << tAge << "\nTotal Savings= " << tSavings;

inData.close();
outData.close();
system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

Hopfully thats formatted correctly.

The program runs fine and dandy when i use:

```
10.45 8.76
13.78

Jake Melon 45
7600

128 76.9
11

Mike Sander 56
800

15.9 43
6400

David James 32
87000.54
```

But when i use:

```
10.45 aaaa
13.78

Jake Melon 45
7600

128 76.9
;

Mike Sander 23
800

15.9 43
w

David James i
87000.54
```

My main while loop (where I read data) doesn't fire for some reason, and all of my values remain at 0. Your help will be greatly appreciated! And I'm sorry for such a long block of text.

Comment: I hope somebody answers your question and helps you out. For me, it's too much code and there are too many ways to solve the problem. It's quite bit more code that what I would call a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yea, I understand that really. Its just tough to do it without including all my stuff so you can see the context of stuff :/

Comment: If you look at your `while` condition, if any one of those inputs fail, the code in the loop will not execute.  The second input is failing.

Comment: OK, thats helping. How would I make it so that it wont break? Is it the fact that its trying to add a string into a double?

Comment: Where do you check that `names[count++]` does not overflow the array? Why not use a vector and push back?

Answer (score 0):

Error recovery is difficult and there are no standard methods (think about how your compiler recovers from a syntax error).

You will need an outer loop for your `while` loop.  You'll want to come up with a design that will help you resynchronize on the input format.  Again, not an easy task.

A simple method is to count the text lines and display the text line where the failure existed and end the program.  From that you can display more information, such as the field that was in error.  Some programmers assume the worst that once an error is found the remaining data can't be trusted.

I recommend putting in place a simple error announcement and safely terminate (clean up, flush to disk, etc.).  Work on getting the remainder of your program working correctly, then come up with better error handling strategies.

Comment: Hmm ok, thanks for the input. I'll try to get it to work and fiddle with it, but its a pain in the ass. The real issue is that he wants us to work through the errors, not just quit the program. Like if we get a string where a double or int should be he wants us to set it to 0

Comment: This is a lot easier.  Don't put all your input in the `while` statement.  Place each input into an `if` statement and if the input failed, clear the error and assign a default value.  Use a different condition to terminate your `while` statement.